# Using rngStory from EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have the below script, that is ment to run from EXCEL, open a word file and then make a search and replace in each StoryRanges in the document.

I get compile error: "Argument not optional" on the line
With rngStory.Find.

So I need to pass an argument to the Find function.

But, if I run the same code from a word document replacing 
"For Each rngStory In WordDoc.StoryRanges"
with 
For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
I have no problem running the code, and here the Find function doesn't need a parameter.

Why is that?

```
Sub test()
  Dim WordApp As Object
  Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Dim WordDoc As Object
  Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("G:\Bruger\KBU\template_file.docx")
  Dim rngStory As Range
  For Each rngStory In WordDoc.StoryRanges
    With rngStory.Find
      .Text = "find text"
      .Replacement.Text = "I'm found"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next rngStory
End Sub
```

BR Kresten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, on Excel, a `Excel.Range` is created (which is different from `Word.Range`). To solve, just define `rngStory` as `Word.Range` and it will work. 
 
I've also changed the way you initialize `WordApp`, since you need to add a `Reference` anyway:

```
Sub test()
  Dim WordApp As New Word.Application
  Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
  Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("G:\Bruger\KBU\template_file.docx")
  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  For Each rngStory In WordDoc.StoryRanges
    With rngStory.Find
      .Text = "find text"
      .Replacement.Text = "I'm found"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next rngStory
End Sub
```

> **Note**: If you haven't, add **Microsoft Word XX.0 Object Library** to your References, otherwise you'll get an error.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling VBA code from different applications (Excel, Word) you are using corresponding application model by default (Excel.Application, Word.Application).

So when you are calling this part

```
Dim rngStory As Range
```

In Excel the `Excel.Range` is created, and in Word `Word.Range` is created.

So trying following workaround:

```
Sub test()
  Dim WordApp As Object
  Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Dim WordDoc As Object
  Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("G:\Bruger\KBU\template_file.docx")
  Dim rngStory
  For Each rngStory In WordDoc.StoryRanges
    With rngStory.Find
      .Text = "find text"
      .Replacement.Text = "I'm found"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next rngStory
End Sub
```

Anyway, you'll have to access Word Object model for `wdFindContinue` value, so switch on reference:

[image: howto]